# Left hand leads, Chip!

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Like Baruchel, Cartwright, and Hamill
heroics and games net me clout

As private as I am general
in battle my pike is drawn out

If I should play white on a chessboard
my clock's less engulfed due to motion

I find the sand cathartic, not bad,
at sinister depth of the ocean!

What am I?

---

*(text below this line is not part of the riddle)*

**Hint:**

> The second half of the riddle is where things get (s)pacific.

> What do Baruchel, Cartwright, and Hamill have in common? Stay 'tooned' for the answer!

Comment: If there is a specific, non-general type of knowledge required (e.g. chemistry, or obscure folklore) then you might want the [[tag:knowledge]] tag, or a more specific one such as [[tag:chemistry]]. If the final answer is a single word then [[tag:word]] applies.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out the answer to that clue since the question was first written...